# Function to split either a string array or string into a string array

Tags: c#, performance, strings

I am programming a language interpreter in C# and have recently created a set of functions that receive either a `string` or a `string[]` and split it by a received string.

For example, with a `string`:

```
"Hey:123:hello:456"
":"
```

It will return this array:

```
{"hey","123","hello","456"}
```

And with a `string[]`:

```
{"a:b","c","d:e:f"}
":"
```

It will return this array:

```
{"a","b","c","d","e","f"}
```

How can I improve efficiency and maybe make it tidier?

```
public string[] SplitRows(object thevar, string delimiter) {

            if (delimiter == "<newline>") delimiter = "\n";

            if (thevar.GetType() == typeof(string)) {
                string temp = (string) thevar;
                return temp.Split(new string[] {
                    delimiter
                }, System.StringSplitOptions.None);
            }
            if (thevar.GetType() == typeof(string[])) {
                return stringarraysplitter((string[]) thevar, delimiter);
            }
            return null;
        }


        public string[] stringarraysplitter(string[] arr, string delimiter) {
            string[][] tempr = new string[arr.Length][];
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++) {
                tempr[i] = arr[i].Split(new string[] {
                    delimiter
                }, System.StringSplitOptions.None);
            }
            System.Collections.Generic.List < string > templist = new System.Collections.Generic.List < string > ();
            for (int i = 0; i < tempr.Length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < tempr[i].Length; j++) {
                    templist.Add(tempr[i][j]);
                }
            }

            return templist.ToArray();
        }
```

Side notes:

- `SplitRows()` is the only main function allowed to receive either a string array or string. Even though I use 2 functions, I cannot create 2 for the 2 variable types.
- `<newline>` is a replacement string for `\n` in my language and can be ignored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (delimiter == "<newline>") delimiter = "\n";
```

Why do you need this? Why not use normal strings?

```
if (thevar.GetType() == typeof(string)) {
```

What's wrong with normal method overloading?

```
if (thevar.GetType() == typeof(string)) {...}
if (thevar.GetType() == typeof(string[])) {...}
return null;
```

If arguments is not valid throw an `ArgumentException`. Don't say "I'll just return `null`, and see where it will go wrong."

```
temp.Split(new string[] {delimiter}, System.StringSplitOptions.None);
```

This bit repeats, and should be extracted into a method.

```
for (int i = 0; i < tempr.Length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < tempr[i].Length; j++) {
```

Use Linq to simplify loop operations.

Here is the cleaned up version:

```
    public IEnumerable<string> Split(string str, string delimiter)
    {
        return str.Split(new[]{delimiter}, StringSplitOptions.None);
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Split(IEnumerable<string> arr, string delimiter) {
        return arr.SelectMany(s => Split(s, delimiter));
    }
```

Comment: Im sorry for <newline> its a replacement string for \n

Comment: I added return null because the ide asked me too return anything,in my language no other option but string or string[] could ever be passed to it

Comment: If you replace `return null` with `throw new ArgumentException("string or string[] only")` IDE (that is compiler) will not complain.

Comment: Could you explain to me,or give me some resourceful links or information on how the 2 last functions you wrote are written? I have never use ienumerable..

Comment: See [Getting Started with LinQ in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx) Consult the Msdn site further as you need to learn about delegates, extension methods, IEnumerable interface etc as you are learning LinQ.

Answer (score 1):

The method `stringarraysplitter()`'s name doesn't follow the [NET naming guideline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx) which states method names should be made out of a verb or a verb-phrase and the method should be name using `PascalCase` casing.
A better name would be `SplitStringArray()`.

Because you already use a `List<string>` you could take advantage of the `AddRange()` method which makes the use of the nested loops redundant and omits the need to have a jagged array at all.

Because the method is public you should check the arguments against `null`.

By using the `var` type it will become more readable.

The placing of the opening brace `{` is different to what a C# developer is used to. In C# we usually place the opening brace on a new line.

Like so

```
public string[] stringarraysplitter(string[] arr, string delimiter) 
{
    if (arr == null || arr.Length == 0) { return arr; }
    if (delimiter == null) { delimiter = "\n"; }

    var results = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>(arr.Length);

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++) 
    {
        results.AddRange(arr[i].Split(new string[] {delimiter}, System.StringSplitOptions.None));
    }

    return results.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: I love that addrange() beautiful!