# Adding a mix of strings and string arrays to an array

Tags: c#, strings, array

Original question:

[Function to split either a string array or string into a string array](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/114618/function-to-split-either-a-string-array-or-string-into-a-string-array)

I was asked why I didn't write multiple functions or something like that. The point of the function is to be a single one and to be able to receive an indefinite number of strings or string arrays and get the job done. Restrictions are not allowed.

The function I have written (creatively-named):

```
public string[] Add(string[] ogarr,object[] toadd)
{

    var results = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();
    results.AddRange(ogarr);

    for (int i = 0; i < toadd.Length; i++)
    {
        if (toadd[i].GetType() == typeof(string[]))
            results.AddRange((string[])toadd[i]);
        else
            results.Add((string)toadd[i]);
    }

        return results.ToArray();
}
```

I use this to test its functionality:

```
string[] temp = new string[]{"123","456","789"};

string[] thing1 = new string[]{"abc","def"};
string thing2 = "ghi";

object[] toadd = new object[] {thing1,thing2 };

temp = Add(temp,toadd);
```

- `temp` is the original string array I want to add things to.
- `thing1` and `thing2` are both things I want to add to that array, one after another, in the order of addition to the `object[]`, obviously.

Disclaimer: I'm not trying to cut bytes; I want aesthetic code! This is my passion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Naming Conventions

As the [Naming Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002(v=vs.110).aspx) states:

> The goal of this chapter is to provide a consistent set of naming
>   conventions that results in names that make immediate sense to
>   developers.

In that sense, the creatively defined method name `Add` and the parameter names `ogarr` and `toadd` will not do.

The [General Naming Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045(v=vs.110).aspx) states:

> Avoid using identifiers that conflict with keywords of widely used
>   programming languages.
>
> Do not use abbreviations or contractions as part of identifier names.
>
> Do favor readability over brevity.

Method name `Add` is a common method name used by collection types to add a new element to the collection. An `Add` method with source as the first parameter and the items to be added as the second parameter does not make sense.

`ogarr` and `toadd` are bad names for parameters and should be changed at least to `sourceArray` and `itemsToAdd` or similar.

And in [Capitalization Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Do use camelCasing for parameter names.

I'm not suggesting to change `ogarr` to `ogArr` and `toadd` to `toAdd` of course. The parameters should have descriptive names in the first place. You can consider `sourceArray` and `itemsToAdd` or similar.

### Possible Improvements

Being consistent with code formatting is important. Consider using curly brackets, always:

```
if (toadd[i].GetType() == typeof(string[]))
{
    results.AddRange((string[])toadd[i]);
}
else
{
    results.Add((string)toadd[i]);
}
```

You say

> restrictions are not allowed.

Then, why restricting the second method parameter to `object[]`? Let's get that as an `IEnumerable`. This way, your method can also operate on `string[]` or `List<T>` instances

```
public string[] Add(string[] sourceArray, IEnumerable itemsToAdd)
```

You can also change the method to be an [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) of `string[]`. This will clearly state the purpose of the method if declared with a good name:

```
public static string[] AddItemsOrRanges(this string[] sourceArray, IEnumerable itemsOrRangesToAdd)
```

You should always check if the parameters are passed in as null. Your code would fail with a null refererence exception at `toadd.Length` if `toadd` is passed as null.

```
if (toadd == null)
{
    // throw ArgumentException() ?
    return ogarr;
}
```

You should also check the items of the passed in collection for null references. If any of the items of the `object[] toadd` would be null, your code would fail with a null refererence exception at `x.GetType()`

```
if (toadd[i] == null)
{
    // throw ArgumentException() ?
    continue;
}
```

Finally, the implementation, with all the naming convention violations and functional confusions fixed, might look like the following:

```
public static string[] AddItemsOrRanges(this string[] sourceArray, IEnumerable itemsOrRangesToAdd)
{
    if (itemsOrRangesToAdd == null)
    {
        // throw ArgumentException() ?
        return sourceArray;
    }

    // It is possible with extension methods to have the self instance this as null
    // because extension methods are actually static methods and can be invoked
    // on a null reference (interesting?)
    // string[] myStringArray = null;
    // string[] finalStringArray = myStringArray.AddItemsOrRanges(new object[] { "Test" });
    // will work!
    if (sourceArray == null)
    {
        // throw ArgumentException() ?
        return sourceArray;
    }

    var results = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>(sourceArray);

    foreach (var itemOrRangeToAdd in itemsOrRangesToAdd)
    {
        if (itemOrRangeToAdd != null)
        {
            if (itemOrRangeToAdd.GetType() == typeof(string[]))
            {
                results.AddRange(itemOrRangeToAdd as string[]);
            }
            else if (itemOrRangeToAdd.GetType() == typeof(string))
            {
                results.Add(itemOrRangeToAdd as string);
            }
            else
            {
                // What to do if the element is neither a string nor a string[]?
                // The (string) cast in the else block would fail in your source code
                // throw ArgumentException() ?
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // How would you determine if the element is to be added or not?
            // is it a null string instance, or is it a null string[] instance?
            // throw ArgumentException() ?
            continue;
        }
    }

    return results.ToArray();
}
```

And calling it would be like:

```
string[] temp = new string[] { "123", "456", "789" };

string[] thing1 = new string[] { "abc", "def" };
string thing2 = "ghi";

object[] toadd = new object[] { thing1, thing2 };

temp = temp.AddItemsOrRanges(toadd);
```

Comment: I love the added function to the string[] idea, i will definitely implement that in my future things,my programming language is type safe,therefor unexpected variable types are not a concern. But you are definitely right,my naming of things is not very good. Thank you

Comment: *restricting the second method parameter to object[]? Let's get that as an IEnumerable.* ... BTW, A `string` IS an array of `char`. This has proved to be a very useful insight.

Answer (score 1):

Just a little thing you can add to Oguz Ozgul answer.. if you always do negative checks first then why not in `foreach` loop? You can easily terminate `else` block.

```
foreach (var itemOrRangeToAdd in itemsOrRangesToAdd)
{
    if (itemOrRangeToAdd == null)
    {
        continue;
    }

    if (itemOrRangeToAdd.GetType() == typeof(string[]))
    {
        results.AddRange(itemOrRangeToAdd as string[]);
    }
    else if (itemOrRangeToAdd.GetType() == typeof(string))
    {
        results.Add(itemOrRangeToAdd as string);
    }
    else
    {
        // What to do if the element is neither a string nor a string[]?
        // The (string) cast in the else block would fail in your source code
        // throw ArgumentException() ?
    }
}
```

Comment: I think having that kind of check inside a loop is cumbersome. I would either gather the non-null values before the loop, or change the foreach to `foreach (var itemOrRangeToAdd in itemsOrRangesToAdd.Where(x=>x!=null))`